# Android Kotlin: How to Update List View From a Different (3rd) Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an Android app in Kotlin, which has a button on the main activity to "Add Players" opening another activity. In this "Add Player" activity, you can choose to manually add a player, which brings up a 3rd "popup" activity. The person enters the info, then hits add. On that click, I want to immediately create a new "Player" object and update the list view of active players on the main activity.

I read to use the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, but the problem is, I can't find a way to get a reference to that adapter (ArrayAdapter) object. If this was Java, I would just make the adapter globally available, or public static, something like that. However, this is Kotlin where everything is confusing as heck for me. I can't make the adapter globally available because I can't initialize the adapter because the "context" parameter which everyone passes "this" doesn't work. I can't make any function changing it to public or static. I also can't lateinit the variable either because Kotlin is mad at me for some reason.

I spent like 2 hours trying to update a stupid ListView for my app. It is pretty disheartening when I try to practice making apps and get caught up in small stuff like this.

I'm sure I have a major misunderstanding, but if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Thank you very much guys,

JT

Comment: The idea of a globally adapter does not sounds good , you should be doing this app with a main activity and different fragments depending on that activity, you can read about navigation components to get an idea on how to navigate between destinations, then, you can use a shared viewmodel between your fragments to pass data to different destinations and finally update your adapter without needing to have one globally, read here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide and here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: Navigation components: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not make your adapter/View/ActivityContext global variable, otherwise, you will get a really big memory issue.**

You should try to use [Local BroadCast receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager). From Activity A which has Adapter, you can register a `Local BroadCast receiver` in `onCreate` to listen to any changing-adapter action. Here's the example:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("YourAdapaterChangeAction.");

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            // check your action with if/else
            //adapter.notify....
        }
},intentFilter);
```

Afterward, you can just fire `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("YourAdapaterChangeAction"));` from any activity to update your adapter.

P/s: another option is to use `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: This worked great for me, marked the answer. The only issue I have with your answer was that it is written in Java, not Kotlin. 

Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

its better if you use onActivityResult() Activity 3-2 2-1 and than get the data in activity one and add into you adpter like this

in Adapter

```
fun onrefresh(List<>lists){
   this.yourlist=lists   
   notifyDataSetChanged() 
   }
```

in activity

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
  if(requestCode==yourcode){
     if(resultCode.RESULT_OK){

         val data=data.get // you data from here 
        // add this into you list data 
        //than set into adapter
       adapter.onrefresh(yourlist)   

      }
    }      
}
```